# Struggling to make an async function wait for a database response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, asynchronous

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me.

I am trying to log users in using a MongoDB backend, I call an async function which makes the fetch call, and returns the login token if I get a 200 response code. :

```
_initialize = async userAddress => {

    const token = await login(userAddress);
    console.log("TOKEN:", token);

    // Do other stuff with the token
  }
```

the login function looks like this:

```
export const login = async address => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ address })
      };
  
      let responseCode;
      fetch(`___ENDPOINT___`, requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
          responseCode = response.status;
          return(response.json());
        })
        .then(data => {
          if(responseCode == 200){
            console.log(data.token)
            const token = data.token;
            return token;
          }
          if(responseCode == 400){
            if(data.message === "User not yet registered"){
              // Do nothing
              return;
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
}
```

The issue that I am having is that the  `await login()` call is not being waited on, instead `token` is console logged as `undefined`.

If I remove the `await` keyword I receive token as :

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

I don't get it, why is token undefined? If I log token in the .then block it is returned successfully, but this only occurs after token has been printed as undefined in the `initialize` function.

Its like the async function initialize is not awaiting the async login function?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `login` function doesn't return a promise. In fact, it doesn't return anything at all. See comments:

```
export const login = async address => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ address })
    };

    // Note: Don't catch erros in this function, let them propagate
    // so the caller knows what happened
  
    // No need for `.then`/`.catch` in an `async` function, use `await`

    // Wait for the initial resaponse
    const response = await fetch(`___ENDPOINT___`, requestOptions);
    const responseCode = response.status;
    if (!response.ok) {
        // Not an OK reseponse
        if (responseCode == 400) {
            // Parse the body to see if we have the message
            const data = await response.json();
            if (data.message === "User not yet registered") {
                // Do nothing
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + responseCode);
    }

    // OK response, read the data from the body, this is also async
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.token;
};
```

Note that `login` will return the token **or** will return `undefined` if the response code was 400 and the body of that response was valid JSON that defined a `message` property with the text `"User not yet registered"`. `_initialize` will need to check for that. Also, `_initialize` should handle any errors from `login`.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I had a feeling there was an issue with returning inside of fetch but didn't quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone knows why the above code doesn't work, that would still be very useful to know, however I came up with a solution :

```
export const login = async address => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ address })
      };

      const response = await fetch(`___ENDPOINT___`, requestOptions)
      const data = await response.json();

      const responseCode = response.status;
      if(responseCode == 200){
        console.log(data.token)
        const token = data.token;
        return token;
      }
      if(responseCode == 400){
        if(data.message === "User not yet registered"){
          // Do nothing
          return;
        }
      }
}
```